# Is this set in $\Bbb{C}^3$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Is $\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{C^3} | z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=1\}$ in the Euclidean topology compact?

We know in $\Bbb{R}^n$ compact iff closed and bounded , but is it true for complex also?

Comment: To answer the non-highlighted question: closed and bounded is equivalent to compact in metric spaces. In the highlighted question: the set is not bounded, hence not compact as $\Bbb C^n$ is a metric space.

Comment: @Clayton just for ref. http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Equivalent_statements_to_compactness_of_a_metric_space among other things.

Comment: Some of the confusion in the answers below could be because the *title* of this question does not match the *content*.  The title asks about a "unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$", which I would understand to mean the set of all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$. That set *is* closed and bounded, hence compact. But the body of the question asks about something else.

Comment: The question is confusing in the context of the title. The set you are considering is not the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}^3$. The unit circle **is** compact but is given by $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2 = 1$.

Comment: @mweiss Thanks , just edited

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal That's better, but "unit circle" is still unclear.

Comment: I've edited for "this set" instead of "unit circle", but my edit got ruled out due to simultaneous of editing, I think...

Comment: This is a rather confusing question for two reasons. Initially the title mentioned the unit circle, but the question referred to a different object. Second, there are two questions, one asking about compactness of a specific set and another asking a general question (does Heine Borel apply to $\mathbb{C}^n$ as well).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the set defined in $\Bbb C^n$ by the "unit sphere equation" $z_1^2+\cdots+z_n^2=1$ is a very different set from the one defined by the corresponding equation in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ (with $2n$ variables).

Since $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, the "unit sphere" in $\Bbb C^3$ is not bounded. For instance, for any $z_1,z_2\in \Bbb C$, the equation $z_1^2+z_2^2+z=1$ has at least one solution.

Comment: Upvoted. Just a side comment: Although your justification is crystal clear, I think the confusion arising from this question stems from the fact that people are mistaking this set for the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Before stating that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, maybe it would be more helpful to simply tell that this is **not** the case, and instead we are looking for the zero-set of a polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the map $i:(\mathbb{R}^2)^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ given by
$i((x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)) = (x_1+i y_1,...,x_n+iy_n)$, with
the norm (squared)  $\|(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n))\|^2 = x_1^2+y_1^2+...+x_n^2+y_n^2$ on $(\mathbb{R}^2)^n$
and
the norm  $\|(z_1,...,z_n)\|^2 = |z_1|^2+...+|z_n|^2$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

We see that $i$ is an isometry, hence $C \subset (\mathbb{R}^2)^n$ is compact **iff** $i(C) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is compact.

In particular, this shows that a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is
compact **iff** it is closed and bounded.

The above example is closed since $(z_1,z_2,z_3) \mapsto z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^3$ is continuous, but since $(t,it,1)$ is in the set for all $t$ we see that it is not bounded, hence not compact.

As an aside, we see that the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is compact,
since $\{(z_1,z_2,z_3)| \|(z_1,z_2,z_3)\| = 1 \}$ is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how exactly you define the set.

If you are interested in

> $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C} | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$

then no, this set is not bounded, hence non-compact.  On the other hand I don't think people would typically refer to that as a "unit sphere" (let alone a "unit circle").  More likely they would ask about

> $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C} | |x|^2 + |y|^2 + |z|^2 = 1 \}$

where $|x|$ denotes the norm, defined by $|x|^2 = \overline{x}x$.  That set *is* closed and bounded, hence compact.